# Can the BH R-package link to boost "math" and "numeric"?

Tags: c++, r, boost

I'm building an R-package for hydrological modelling using the C++ boost library.

The package requires:

- boost::math::gamma_distribution
- boost::math::cdf
- boost::math::isnan

Would the BH R-package work in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure should.  Boost math is a header only library only; so we can test the boost tgamma function using Dirks [Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-boost-with-bh/) as a model

Something along the lines of:

```
// Use brandnew CRAN package BH for Boost headers

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>

#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH

using namespace boost::math;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector boost_gamma( Rcpp::NumericVector x ) {
  foreach( double& elem, x ) {
    elem = boost::math::tgamma(elem);
  };

  return x;
}
```

and then a quick check:

```
> identical( boost_gamma(0:10 + 1), factorial(0:10) )
[1] TRUE
```

Not that the test means too much, except to say that the headers are easily included and usable.

Take a look at the [BigMemory Description](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/bigmemory/DESCRIPTION?view=markup&root=bigmemory) file's `Depends` and `LinkingTo` and notice the `BH` there.

Lastly, you can keep up to date on the changes to what the BH package is setup for by looking at it's [News](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/news.html) page.

Have fun!